# k-nn, objective function and neighborhood definitions

Tags: machine-learning, math, knn

**Summary** : I try to write the mathematical formulation of the objective function of knn and relate it to the neighborhood definition.

**Problem:**
Given  distance of choice d.
I want to define the neighborhood N_k, of k  neighbors for a new sample x'.
I want to express the creation of this neighborhood set as a function of  the distance.
But I am not sure how one can "create  a set" in mathematics language.
Below is the section I am editing

[image]

**Relevant questions**. Some extremenly relevant questions not giving the exact answer:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219655/k-nn-computational-complexity
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420416/does-knn-have-a-loss-function

Linked question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/501229/i-want-to-formulate-mathematically-the-k-nn-objective-function-and-neighborhood

Comment: I've always seen this delta called "Kronecker delta". The Dirac function or Dirac measure is something else.

Comment: So what's your question exactly? Are you looking for an elegant way to phrase " N_k(x') is the set made of the k elements x that have the smallest distance to x' "?